# Where is UserProfile or ApplicationUser model class inside MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, roles

I have a hard time finding `UserProfile/ApplicationUser` in the MVC 5 application. I would like to add this field: `public virtual ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }` to `UserProfile/ApplicationUser` class.

I want do this to use Mr. Chris Pratt's advice: [How to associate list of objects with user(Account) in ASP .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679695/how-to-associate-list-of-objects-with-useraccount-in-asp-net-mvc/24680142?noredirect=1#comment38267002_24680142)

EDIT: Will Entity Framework will understand the association between Meeting and USER if I add in class Meeting field public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; } in code first approach?

I got only this:

[image]

Comment: ApplicationUser is in your IdentityModels.cs

Comment: @Rook Will Entity Framework will understand the association between `Meeting` and USER if I add in `class Meeting` field `public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }` in code first approach?

Comment: yeah, it is possible.